# Songs on memory card does not appear in music player on Samsung Galaxy S2

Tags: samsung, music

I recently bought 16 GB SD card to store music on my Samsung Galaxy S2. I transferred about 500 songs from my pc to this new SD card but when I open the default music player app on my Galaxy S2 I can see only 15-20 songs. Where are the rest of the songs? Same SD card works perfectly on my brothers Sony Xperia Z1. Can anyone please help me to figure out what is wrong with my Galaxy S2?

Comment: Have you rebooted your device? Check whether the Media Scanner successfully scanned your SD card and make sure that no `.nomedia` file is present in any of your folders. Also make sure none of the folders have a `.` (dot) as their first character.

Comment: You are right. There was a .nomedia file in the folder. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Check if those songs are in a format which is supported by the music player you are using. If they are in Mp3, this is obvious. If not, check your app's compatibility.
2. Check if the SD card is recognized by your phone at all: open a file manager and see if you see it and can navigate through it
3. Check if your media player is looking in the SD card: go in your player's settings and check your library options. Note that music players offer filters (to avoid ringtones and such be included in your library): they go from name, to format, to length, to folder. Check all those filters. Then do a library rescan
4. Check for `.nomedia` files inside the main folder of your SD card or of your music archive: if such a file is included, your media player is told to skip that folder in order to avoid including ringtones and such, again
5. Check if your songs are properly tagged. Music players will organized your library with tags (informations about Artist, Album, Genre, Year, Track Number and Title) rather than location and filename.

Comment: Thanks! This .nomedia file was the main culprit. Everything is working fine now.

Comment: What if it's none of these? The only thing that ever works for me is to use a third party rescanner. Is this how Android is supposed to work?...

Answer (score 0):

My best solution would be to open up the "MyFiles" Application (I believe the S2 has this) and transfer those songs to the default mp3 folder. If you experience issues with that I would recommend downloading and using a  different music player application.

Comment: I tried transferring music files to default MP3 folder but it didn't work. Same issue with the other Music apps like Poweramp.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me on Android 6 marshmallow:

1. Go to USB storage settings, unmount then mount SD card (no need to physically remove)
2. Go to app settings, clear cache and data for the music app
3. Open the app again. Bingo! It worked